# Probability when doing multiple independent tests with a prior probabilty

Tags: probability, statistics

A medical diagnostics test is `p` accurate on people with the disease and `q` accurate on people without.  Also `r` fraction of people actually have the disease.  0 <= p,q,r <= 1

If a person tested positive for the disease 4 times what is the probability he actually has the disease expressed in terms of `p, q, r`?

---

I'm not sure how accuracies `p` and `q` are defined. But I think `p = p_true_positive / p_positive` and `q = q_true_negative / q_negative`.

`p = p_true_positive / r`, `q = p_true_negative / (1-r)`

Now I was thinking think that the probability that he doesn't have a disease is
`(1-p)^4`, so that he does is `1 - (1-p)^4`, but this seems not to be true.

Comment: You must use Bayes' rule and incorporate the prior probability as well.

Comment: Are you assuming the tests are independent, rather than making the same mistake each time?

Comment: I am, yes. They are independent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Bayes' rule (and assuming test independence):

$$P(D|++++) = \frac{P(++++|D) P(D)}{P(++++)} \\
= \frac{P(++++|D) P(D)}{P(D) P(++++|D) + P(-D)P(++++|-D)}$$

Here $+$ denotes a positive result on the test, $P(D) = r$ is the prior probability of having the disease, $P(-D) = 1 - P(D) = 1-r$ is the prior probability of *not* having the disease, and $P(++++|D)$ is the probability of getting four positive tests given the patient has the disease.

Just plug in your numbers.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Really makes sense. Let me just ask you if for example one test was negative and three positive, I would use: 
`P(D|+++-) = P(+++-|D) * P(D) / P(+++-) = P(+++-|D) * P(D) / [P(D) * P(+++-|D) + P(-D) * P(+++-|-D)]` ?

Comment: Correct........